# How to order an Array in PHP that will be than passed to an Android App - Extra " [ " appearing

Tags: php, android, arrays

I am having trouble ordering and array in PHP before reading in an Android App.

Observation:

1 - I can´t order the array as I am reading from the DB, because the information that I am considering as the 1st criteria is time based.

2 - I am able to pass the information to the Android App and there is no problem on that end.

Here is the original code.

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

        //array temporário      
        $cidade = $row2['CidadeHospital'];
        $estado = $row2['EstadoHospital'];
        $localidade = $cidade . " - " . $estado;



        if (validacao_apontamento($row2['d_h_ultima_lotacao']) == 'valido') {
            if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 1) {
                $lotacao = 'vazio';
                $ordem = 1;
            } else {
                if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 2) {
                    $lotacao = 'pouco cheio';
                    $ordem = 2;
                } else {
                    if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 3) {
                        $lotacao = 'muito cheio';
                        $ordem = 3;
                    } else {
                        if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 4) {
                            $lotacao = 'lotado';
                            $ordem = 4;
                        } else {
                            $lotacao = 'sem registro';
                            $ordem = 9;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $lotacao = 'sem registro';
            $ordem = 9;
        }

        $hospital = array("pid" => $row2['PID'], "nome" => $row2['NomeHospital'], "localidade" => $localidade, "lotacao" => $lotacao, "ordem" => $ordem);
        array_push($response["hospitais"], $hospital);
    }
```

Here is the response that is read by App.

```
{"hospitais":[{"pid":"1","nome":"Madre Teresa","localidade":"Belo Horizonte - MG","lotacao":"sem registro","ordem":9}, .... , {"pid":"230","nome":"Fel\u00edcio Rocho","localidade":"Belo Horizonte - MG","lotacao":"pouco cheio","ordem":2}],"areadebusca":"N\u00e3o existem hospitais cadastrados pr\u00f3ximos, exibidos todos do Estado.","successo":1}
```

The solution I tried was this:

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

        //array temporário      
        $cidade = $row2['CidadeHospital'];
        $estado = $row2['EstadoHospital'];
        $localidade = $cidade . " - " . $estado;



        if (validacao_apontamento($row2['d_h_ultima_lotacao']) == 'valido') {
            if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 1) {
                $lotacao = 'vazio';
                $ordem = 1;
            } else {
                if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 2) {
                    $lotacao = 'pouco cheio';
                    $ordem = 2;
                } else {
                    if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 3) {
                        $lotacao = 'muito cheio';
                        $ordem = 3;
                    } else {
                        if ($row2['ultima_lotacao'] == 4) {
                            $lotacao = 'lotado';
                            $ordem = 4;
                        } else {
                            $lotacao = 'sem registro';
                            $ordem = 9;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $lotacao = 'sem registro';
            $ordem = 9;
        }

        $hospital [] = array("pid" => $row2['PID'], "nome" => $row2['NomeHospital'], "localidade" => $localidade, "lotacao" => $lotacao, "ordem" => $ordem);

    }

    $sort = array();
    foreach ($hospital as $k => $v) {
        $sort['ordem'][$k] = $v['ordem'];
        $sort['nome'][$k] = $v['nome'];
    }
    array_multisort($sort['ordem'], $sort['nome'], SORT_ASC, $hospital);

    array_push($response["hospitais"], $hospital);
```

The answer I got now is:

```
{"hospitais":[[{"pid":"2","nome":"Lifecenter","localidade":"Belo Horizonte - MG","lotacao":"vazio","ordem":1}, .... , {"pid":"10","nome":"Vila da Serra","localidade":"Nova Lima - MG","lotacao":"sem registro","ordem":9}]],"areadebusca":"N\u00e3o existem hospitais cadastrados pr\u00f3ximos, exibidos todos do Estado.","successo":1}
```

As you can see, at the beginning of each array, there is an extra " [ " before the entries.

```
1st - {"hospitais":[{"pid": ....
2nd - {"hospitais":[[{"pid": ....
```

The thing is that if the adittion on the secon " [ " , my APP is now unable to read the response.

Comment: You need to show what's in `$response` to start with. but as written, you'd be putting an array into `$response['hospitais']`, making that entry an array.

Answer (score 0):

On the solution I tried, Instead of using

```
array_push($response["hospitais"], $hospital);
```

I used

```
$response = array ('hospitais' => $hospital);
```